# Unable to get Javascript myFunction() to run var requiredFields = document.getElementById before going to next command

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
  var requiredFields = document.getElementById('specialTxtarea');
  window.alert('Thank for your Reservation');
  window.location = 'index.html';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="checkin" class="col-2 col-form-label">Check-In</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="checkin" name="checkin" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" wfd-id="13">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="checkout" class="col-2 col-form-label">Check-Out</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="checkout" name="checkout" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" wfd-id="12">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="text" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="text" name="text" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" wfd-id="11">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email_id" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required="required" class="form-control" wfd-id="10">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="phone" class="col-2 col-form-label">Phone #</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="11 numeric" type="tel" required pattern="\d{11}" label="11 digits" class="form-control" wfd-id="9">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2">Room Type</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_0" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" checked wfd-id="8">
        <label for="roomtype_0" class="custom-control-label">Deluxe Room</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_1" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" wfd-id="7">
        <label for="roomtype_1" class="custom-control-label">Junior Suite</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_2" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" wfd-id="6">
        <label for="roomtype_2" class="custom-control-label">Family Suite</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_3" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" wfd-id="5">
        <label for="roomtype_3" class="custom-control-label">Cameron Suite</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_4" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" wfd-id="4">
        <label for="roomtype_4" class="custom-control-label">Foster Suite</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2">Room Preference</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input name="preference" id="preference_0" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="No Preference" required="required" wfd-id="3">
        <label for="preference_0" class="custom-control-label">No Preference</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input name="preference" id="preference_1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="Non Smoking" required="required" wfd-id="2">
        <label for="preference_1" class="custom-control-label">Non Smoking</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input name="preference" id="preference_2" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="Smoking" required="required" wfd-id="1">
        <label for="preference_2" class="custom-control-label">Smoking</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="adults" class="col-2 col-form-label">Adults</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <select id="adults" name="adults" class="custom-select" required="required" wfd-id="16">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="children" class="col-2 col-form-label">Children</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <select id="children" name="children" class="custom-select" wfd-id="15">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="textarea" class="col-2 col-form-label">Special Requirement</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <textarea id="specialTxtarea" name="specialTxtarea" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" wfd-id="17"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-2 col-10">
      <button name="alpsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" wfd-id="18" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

This is for my assignment. For this reservation form, I am not required to use PHP to validate. What I am required is to have the form validate the field and upon submit, a response using window alert to pop out.

My lecturer has actually worked through with me and managed to get my codes to work. But somehow.. after I got home. I am unable to get the form to validate prior to submit and go back to home page

I was expecting that the form created will check through all field and be prompt prior to submit button pressed and go through window.alert with a Thank you response and bring back to index.html

Comment: Assigning a variable doesn't cause any validation to happen.

Comment: You don't do any validation in your function. You never "check through all field".

Comment: The redirect in `myFunction()` will never be executed, because submitting the form cancels scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the on click on submit and added action="javascript:myFunction();" for the form and it will work here's the code for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form id="myForm" action="javascript:myFunction();">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="checkin" class="col-2 col-form-label">Check-In</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="checkin" name="checkin" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" wfd-id="13">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="checkout" class="col-2 col-form-label">Check-Out</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="checkout" name="checkout" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" wfd-id="12">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="text" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="text" name="text" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" wfd-id="11">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email_id" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required="required" class="form-control" wfd-id="10">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="phone" class="col-2 col-form-label">Phone #</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="11 numeric" type="tel" required pattern="\d{11}" label="11 digits" class="form-control" wfd-id="9">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa "></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2">Room Type</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_0" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" checked wfd-id="8">
        <label for="roomtype_0" class="custom-control-label">Deluxe Room</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_1" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" wfd-id="7">
        <label for="roomtype_1" class="custom-control-label">Junior Suite</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_2" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" wfd-id="6">
        <label for="roomtype_2" class="custom-control-label">Family Suite</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_3" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" wfd-id="5">
        <label for="roomtype_3" class="custom-control-label">Cameron Suite</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        <input name="roomtype" id="roomtype_4" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="" wfd-id="4">
        <label for="roomtype_4" class="custom-control-label">Foster Suite</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2">Room Preference</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input name="preference" id="preference_0" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="No Preference" required="required" wfd-id="3">
        <label for="preference_0" class="custom-control-label">No Preference</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input name="preference" id="preference_1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="Non Smoking" required="required" wfd-id="2">
        <label for="preference_1" class="custom-control-label">Non Smoking</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input name="preference" id="preference_2" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="Smoking" required="required" wfd-id="1">
        <label for="preference_2" class="custom-control-label">Smoking</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="adults" class="col-2 col-form-label">Adults</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <select id="adults" name="adults" class="custom-select" required="required" wfd-id="16">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="children" class="col-2 col-form-label">Children</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <select id="children" name="children" class="custom-select" wfd-id="15">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="textarea" class="col-2 col-form-label">Special Requirement</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <textarea id="specialTxtarea" name="specialTxtarea" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" wfd-id="17"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-2 col-10">
      <button name="alpsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" wfd-id="18">Submit</button>

    </div>

  </div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var requiredFields = document.getElementById('specialTxtarea');
  window.alert('Thank for your Reservation');
  //window.location = 'index.html';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not make the code in your answer a stack snippet like in the question?

Comment: M sorry that was my bad.

Comment: Hi Melvin,
Thanks so much, its working brilliantly.